# httpd own build stay in foreground in docker

Tags: docker, apache, background, foreground

i want to run my own httpd build into docker
everything works except that "docker run" hang on console ( stay in foreground )

for example, if i run the official image, httpd **runs in the background** of docker (that's what i want for mine ):

> docker run -dit --name my-apache-app -p 8080:80 -v
> "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4

the Dockerfile of the official image is here and it inspired myself:
https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/077141ee37fca63972292c562ec0f632d0f831b1/2.4/Dockerfile

Here is the end of my **Dockerfile**:

```
COPY httpd.sh /usr/local/bin/httpd-background 
RUN /bin/chmod +x /usr/local/bin/httpd-* 
EXPOSE 80 
CMD ["httpd-background"]
```

content of **httpd.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/bin/httpd24/bin/httpd -t if [ ! "$?" == "0" ]; then echo "error
in httpd config file"; exit 1; fi 
exec /home/bin/httpd24/bin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

i tried with and without the "exec", and with -DFOREGROUND and -DNO_DETACH

any help appreciated
thanks !

Comment: The main container process generally needs to run as a "foreground" process; the `docker run -d` option makes Docker launch the container as a "background" process (the actual mechanism is slightly different from shell job control).  Does this help clarify things for you?  What behavior do you need that this combination of commands isn't producing?

Comment: all this time, i just missed the -d parameters ... everything else seems now OK ! thanks !